# How to fix Hadoop WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred error on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop, hadoop2

I have installed Java `openjdk version "10.0.2"`and `Hadoop 2.9.0` successfully. All processes  are running well

```
hadoopusr@amalendu:~$ jps
19888 NameNode
20388 DataNode
20898 NodeManager
20343 SecondaryNameNode
20539 ResourceManager
21118 Jps
```

But when ever i am trying to execute any command like `hdfs dfs -ls /` getting this warnings

```
hadoopusr@amalendu:~$ hdfs dfs -ls /
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil (file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-2.9.0.jar) to method sun.security.krb5.Config.getInstance()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
18/09/04 00:29:24 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

Please help how to fix this.
This is my ~/.bashrc file configuration

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"
```

Comment: Use Java 8 for Hadoop. Spark, Scala, etc. do not yet support Java 9 or newer yet.

Comment: your  datanode  had been closed

Comment: @H.king Yes, I have fixed it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed in Hadoop 3.3 and 3.2.2 via.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-10848

Answer (score 17):

There is nothing you can do about these warnings, this is related to jigsaw project and strong(er) encapsulation.

Basically there is some class called `sun.security.krb5.Config` that is part of some "module" called `java.security.jgss`. This module "defines" what it exports (what others can use out of it) and to whom. This also means in plain english that this is not for the public usage - don't touch it; well `hadoop` did, it's part of their effort to fix this. You can report this or try to upgrade hadoop, may be this is already fixed.

Comment: Thanks, But is there any way to hide this warnings ?

Comment: @AmalenduKar no, these are issued by the compiler

Comment: Sir i removed java 11 and installed java 8, All are gone but "WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable " this occour.

Comment: @AmalenduKar this is entirely different and you should post a different question about it most probably

Comment: @AmalenduKar The message means that the hadoop native libraries are compiled 32-bit and you are running on a 64-bit setup. You can ignore that message for a small Hadoop setup.

Comment: You can use the --add-opens option to temporarily open the sun.security.krb5 package. That will eliminate the warning but it is important to make sure that the Hadoop maintainers are aware of the issue. Once the JDK internals are fully encapsulated then hacks like this will break.

Comment: @AlanBateman that is one of the reasons I did not want to post that... thank you!

Answer (score 4):

this problem is due to latest java upgrades.please configure it with java 8.its working swiftly.