# hadoop fs -mkdir :no such directory

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I have been following [this](https://github.com/TuanHenry/Step-by-step-install-Hadoop-on-Windows-10/wiki) article regarding installing Hadoop and I have completed the article.

However, upon trying to make a new hdfs folder, the following error occured.

```
C:\hadoop-2.8.0\bin>hadoop fs -mkdir /user/input
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil (file:/C:/hadoop-2.8.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-2.8.0.jar) to method sun.security.krb5.Config.getInstance()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
mkdir: `/user/input': No such file or directory
```

This stumps me because I am trying to make a folder, not executing a -ls or -put command.

For the record, I am on Windows 10 on a command prompt that is run as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether all services are up and running namenode, datanode etc.... using jps command as shown in the reference.

Also, Try configuring to Java8.

Refer : [hadoop-warning-an-illegal-reflective-access-operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52155078/how-to-fix-hadoop-warning-an-illegal-reflective-access-operation-has-occurred-e)